# ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() regresa nulo

Tags: java, java-8, javac

Tengo el siguiente problema usando la interfaz `JavaCompiler`, alguien puede ayudarme

```
public class createRobot {

    public static void create(double[] chromo) {
        createRobotFile(chromo); // create file
        compile(); // now compile it
    }
    
    public static void compile () {
        String fileToCompile = "C:/Users/Angelito/eclipse-workspace/PracticaRobocode/src/SamBot.java"; // which file to compile * rhyming :) *
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile); // run compile
    }
    
    public static void createRobotFile(double[] chromo){
        try {
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Angelito/eclipse-workspace/PracticaRobocode/src/SamBot.java"); // file name to create
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            
            //start code
            out.write("package custom; \n " +
                "import robocode.*; \n" +
                "import robocode.Robot;\n" +
                "import java.awt.Color;\n" +
                "public class SamBot extends Robot {\n");
            
                    // build up robot logic in here
                    // access chromosomes from array to set as variables
            
                    out.append("int foo = (int)" + chromo[0] + ";\n");
                    
                    // end of robot

            out.append("\n}");
              
            out.close(); // close output stream
            
        } catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Mensaje de error]

Comment: Por favor tu código como texto

Comment: veo que estás usando un JRE para correrlo, te aseguraste que tu `tools.jar` estuviera en el classpath antes de correr tu aplicación? (PD: ese tools.jar desaparece en versiones superiores de Java)